# php constants and EOT

Tags: php, html, printing, echo

is it possible to display constants php's EOT? for example:

```
<?
  define('Hey', "HellO");
  echo
<<<EOT
Hey
EOT;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to being able to display HTML/PHP and even PHP constants and then storing the extended string into a variable:

### my_file.php

```
Welcome back <?=$User -> get_display_name(); ?>!
```

### index.php

```
<?

  define('HEY', "Welcome to my website!");

  ob_start(); ?>
  <div id=welcomeBox>
  <? if($User -> is_real()): ?>
  <? require_once("my_file.php"); ?>
  <? else: ?>
  <?=HEY; ?> Click <a href=JavaScript:SignUp()>here</a> to sign up!
  <? endif; ?>
  </div>
  <?
  $page_body = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean(); ?>
  <div>
    Aye
  </div>
<?=$page_body;?>
```

### If the user is real the output would be something like:

```
  <div>
    Aye
  </div>
  <div id=welcomeBox>
    Welcome back Johnny Cash!
  </div>
```

### Otherwise it would say:

```
  <div>
   Aye
  </div>
  <div id=welcomeBox>
    Welcome to my website! Click <a href=JavaScript:SignUp()>here</a> to sign up!
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  Just like you can't display a constant inside of a string.  There are only two real ways to access a constant's value:

Directly in code:

```
$foo = Hey;
```

Or using the [`constant`](https://www.php.net/constant) function:

```
$foo = constant('Hey');
```

Comment: The hrids way would be to do a concatenation liek 'Echo static: ' . Hey . ' is fun';

Comment: @iTroubs: Assuming you mean "third way", no it isn't, that is "Directly in code", so it is the first way again.

Comment: @iTroubs: to PHP's parser, it's identical to putting it directly in code (the same parser tokens are generated)...

Answer (score 1):

No, the heredoc syntax (<<<) acts just like a double quoted string in PHP.  It will expand variables, but not constants.

You can see a comment in the PHP documentation indicating this [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php#19363).  There is also an editors note on the comment saying that it is correct.